# CV journal club?

Tags: discussion, chat

We have an [awesome chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) (yes, it is [awesome by design](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/talkative-and-precognitive-badges/)), and a small traffic there. Yet there is an idea to organize a periodic meetup to boost the chat popularity. Photo.SE has for instance photo critique sessions; we could have a some kind of journal club.

So, two questions:

- Do you think it is a good idea? (=Would you participate?)
- When could it be scheduled to gather maximal audience?

Comment: **NB**: Time & date for first journal club now set. See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/674/449 for details and to propose & vote on article to discuss.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I think it is a great idea providing JC content is defined and planned in advance (so that interested people can reserve some time). Maybe we could start with focused topics based on recent posts (where diverging opinions were expressed, or with large voting rate on Q or A), or more general ones (no idea about that), or users might suggest some topics based on recent literature/work that will be submitted to a voting process (JC participants or CV users).

I have no idea of a time that would best fit with everyone's agenda. It seems, however, that most users are somewhere between US and Europe (I must apologize for extrapolating this way), so 5pm in NYC means 11pm in France/Germany (a little bit late). So I guess we have to find a compromise, e.g. 1 or 2pm US time?

About frequency, what is your idea? I won't expect a great audience on a daily basis, but maybe every 2 weeks or every month will be a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea.  And the chat room allows you to schedule events in there.

Depending on the frequency, timing, etc., I would participate.

Answer (score 4):

I too like the idea. To maximise appeal it will useful to have a range of types of papers considered for the journal club; theoretical through to applied.

I know a lot of us are academics here, but how do we solve the issue of access to journals for those without subscriptions?

I would participate, though like @Shane, it would depend on timing and frequency. Once a month would be fine, any more than that and it will start eating into the day job.