# First Cross Validated Journal Club

Tags: discussion, chat, journal-club

EDIT3: CVJC1 finished; you can read the transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/conversation/cross-validated-journal-club-1).

EDIT2: I have still no response from the author, yet I think it should go as planned: 12/17/2010, 16:00UTC, we will discuss text mining in general basing on the article proposed by @onestop:

[Jeffrey L. Solka. Text data mining: Theory and methods. Statistical Surveys 2008](http://www.i-journals.org/ss/viewarticle.php?id=16&layout=abstract)

and possibly also text mining tools in R, after the paper proposed by @chl:

[Ingo Feinerer, Kurt Hornik, David Meyer. Text Mining Infrastructure in R. JSS 2008](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05)

If you want to come, please [register to the event here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18/ten-fold?tab=schedule).
(This is not obligatory or necessary to participate, but you'll get an e-mail notification)

---

[See also previous question.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/667/cv-journal-club)

Based on the [discussion on the chat yesterday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/224007#224007) (thanks for chl, csgillespie, Gavin Simpson and Shane), the initial idea for this clarified.
So the CVJC:

- will be held monthly probably Fridays, maybe 16:00UTC (this may be changing so that each major time zone will have equal chance to be in a comfortable time)
- the discussed article(s)

  - will be picked on a meta thread like this before the chat event
  - must be OpenAccess or preprints/reprints, so everyone could read them
  - we (mods) will try to contact the authors and invite them to join the discussion (their acceptance will be a required constrain to use a preprint)
- may also appear in a form of R package promotion event when package author shows a guided demo of its capabilities (this needs some further refinement of technical details)

So please, propose the articles as answers to this question. In a first approximation the first CVJC is scheduled for 16:00UTC 17.12.2010.

EDIT: To settle timetable, let's say the deadline for paper suggestions is 23:59UTC 14.12.2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this article from the same journal I suggested before?

Jeffrey L. Solka. Text data mining: Theory and methods. *Statistical Surveys* 2008; 2: 94-112. DOI: [10.1214/07-SS016](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/07-SS016)

Reasons: open access, not very long (c. 12 pages of main text), not very mathematical (5 equations, no calculus or measure theory), seems quite a hot topic at the moment, I know nothing about it myself (so i'm not offering to 'present' it! In fact i doubt i can make the meeting this friday, sorry...)

Comment: @onestop And nicely complemented by a paper in the JSS about TM, [Text Mining Infrastructure in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper). I'm afraid I may not be available next Friday, but it's already a good start.

Comment: Ok, this seems a pretty nice idea. @chl The time and date may change.

Comment: Nice paper, but you should notice that while the paper is not very long, it introduces a lot of different problems that are not really specific and that can lead to several different huge discussions (for example: dimensionality reduction, distance between object, data visualisation, clustering, ...). I guess a paper for such a discussion should be more specific ?

Comment: @robin Good point, but I think it is good -- I don't know how many people will come, so more chances for discussion means less chance for deadly silence ;-)

Comment: There is an other problem -- the author works for US Navy and seemingly his e-mail is confidential...

Comment: @mbq - unless this is the same Jeff L. Solka?? http://binf.gmu.edu/~jsolka/

Comment: @onestop Oh, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How about an article from *[Statistical Surveys](http://www.i-journals.org/ss/)*, an open-access peer-reviewed journal that publishes what its title suggests?

This one in the current volume caught my eye for some reason:

- Arlot S, Celisse A. A survey of cross-validation procedures for model selection. *Statistical Surveys* 2010; 4:40-79. DOI: [10.1214/09-SS054](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/09-SS054)

-- but I haven't even checked the contents pages of the previous volumes so i'm open to other suggestions, especially ones with fewer than 40 pages.

Comment: (+1) This one is particularly theoretical (IMO), and hard to read for people with few mathematical statistics background. But SS has very good papers, as Statistical Science does. I need to check myself.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion; topic looks nice, but the size is be quite discouraging.

Comment: @mbq Statistical Science is a longer-established review journal but isn't open access. Sorry hadn't read past the intro of that one, and doing so now, agree it does rapidly get too theoretical-mathematical. @mbq agree about the size too! Maybe I should withdraw this specific article as a suggestion. Journal still looks a promising source of open-access review articles though.