# Second Cross Validated Journal Club -- date

Tags: discussion, journal-club

Last year we have chosen the topic for the [second CVJC](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/second-cross-validated-journal-club), Global Warming and Hockey Stick Controversy -- now it is time to place it in the space-time.

So please add your date suggestions as answers and vote for those that are convenient for you. Please note the new [full-day discussion + 3 concentration sessions organisation](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/685/second-cross-validated-journal-club), which in theory should make it timezone-independent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Friday, January 21st

We could also make it on-going as "the third Friday each month", or something along that line (although this may be premature).

Comment: The idea of reserving every third Friday looks good.